# Is it possible to remove a generic parameter of this method?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a navigation service for my ViewModels - there is just one issue with it. I hope i am just missing out something here / doing something wrong because otherwise i suppose i would have to wait for [concepts](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/110) to be introduced to c#.

My desire is to
**turn this:**

```
    public SomeConsumer()
    {
        INavigationService service = null;
        service.NavigateAsync<SomeViewModel, OneParam>(new OneParam());
    }
```

**into this:**

```
    public SomeConsumer()
    {
        INavigationService service = null;
        service.NavigateAsync<SomeViewModel>(new OneParam());
    }
```

**or this:**

```
    public SomeConsumer()
    {
        INavigationService service = null;
        service.NavigateAsync<SomeViewModel>(new TwoParam());
    }
```

**but PREVENT this:**

```
    public SomeConsumer()
    {
        INavigationService service = null;
        service.NavigateAsync<SomeViewModel>(new ThreeParam());
    }
```

The setup is as following:

```
    public interface INavigationReceiver<TNavigationArgument>
        where TNavigationArgument : INavigationArgument
    {
        Task NavigateAsync(TNavigationArgument argument);
    }

    public interface INavigationArgument
    {

    }

    public class OneParam : INavigationArgument
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class TwoParam : INavigationArgument
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public int Value2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class ThreeParam : INavigationArgument
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public int Value2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeViewModel : INavigationReceiver<OneParam>, INavigationReceiver<TwoParam>
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task NavigateAsync(OneParam argument)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task NavigateAsync(TwoParam argument)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public interface INavigationService
    {
        Task NavigateAsync<TReceiver, TArgument>(TArgument argument)
            where TReceiver : INavigationReceiver<TArgument>
            where TArgument : INavigationArgument;
    }

    public class SomeConsumer
    {
        public SomeConsumer()
        {
            INavigationService service = null;
            service.NavigateAsync<SomeViewModel, OneParam>(new OneParam());
        }
    }
```

If this is possible without concepts i would be really curious to know.

Comment: In your current set up you have no way of stopping some one using Three Param in your NavigateAsync method. And Since you want to be be able to use OneParam and TwoParam (but not three) the only way you're really going to get close, is making One and Two share an interface (or base class i suppose) that Three does not have

Comment: Furthermore there´s no way to set only a part of the generic arguments while omitting others. Either specifiy all or none.

Comment: Don't use generics when you want a method to have a small, finite, defined in advance list of possible types.  Generics are to be used when a large, unspecified number of unknown types needs to be allowed.  If you want to allow two different types to be provided, use two overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this solves your issue, but I think the following might be the closest thing to what you want based on the current features of C#:

```
public interface INavigationService
{
    //The implementation of this would simply create an instance
    //of something similar to the NavigationServiceStep2 class and return it
    INavigationServiceStep2<TArgument> NavigateAsync<TArgument>(TArgument argument)
        where TArgument : INavigationArgument;
}

public interface INavigationServiceStep2<TArgument> where TArgument : INavigationArgument
{
    Task ForReceiver<TReceiver>() where TReceiver : INavigationReceiver<TArgument>;
}

public class NavigationServiceStep2<TArgument> : INavigationServiceStep2<TArgument>
    where TArgument : INavigationArgument
{
    private readonly TArgument argument;

    public NavigationServiceStep2(TArgument argument)
    {
        this.argument = argument;
    }

    public Task ForReceiver<TReceiver>() where TReceiver : INavigationReceiver<TArgument>
    {
        //real implementation here
    }
}

public class SomeConsumer
{
    public SomeConsumer()
    {
        INavigationService service = null;
        service.NavigateAsync(new OneParam()).ForReceiver<SomeViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Because C# currently does not allow you to specify some type arguments and have other type arguments inferred automatically, the only way around this is to convert the single method call into two method calls.

There is a championed proposal for this by the way: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1349

Comment: clever approach. will modify it to see if i can get that work perfectly and flag as answer if it is possible to do so. Looks like a very promising attempt one way or another